# Can speech Synthesizer be programmed to read text more accurately

Tags: vb.net, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I have a program that uses a `SpeechSynthesizer` by reading each sentence in a textbox. Is there a way to program the synthesizer to recognize the difference between a period and a question mark, in order to read the text more accurately?

Comment: You mean to add an upward inflection when the sentence is a question?

Comment: yes, to make it sounds like a question

Comment: Don't think it's possible with the SpeechSynthesizer class.

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this, because the text needs to be read and understood according to question or regular sentence

Comment: Not that I know of..

Answer (score 0):

If your system has a commercial TTS engine (that does the actual synthesis inside the SpeechSynthesizer class) then it should be doing this for you automatically. Even the most basic TTS system will honor commas, periods, question marks and exclamation points. Did you disable prosody somehow in your initialization?

Comment: not sure what you mean, how could i check if i disabled it?